# How to pass keycloak login page language with URL

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

is it possible to pass language with a login URL?

I know now Keycloak supports multiple languages and after enabling this feature I can use it. Currently, I can only change that language after going to the login page. I want to show the login page with the given language. Is there any way to pass language with the login page URL using a query parameter or header value?

After loading the login page I checked it URL and end of that URL have a query parameter like `kc_locale=en`. I try to use this query parameter but it not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In version 7.0.0+ below format works:

```
https://...../auth/realms/..../protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=account&redirect_uri=...&state=0&response_type=code&scope=openid&**kc_locale=cs**
```

For version 13.0.0+ use element **ui_locales**=cs.

Answer (score 7):

I`m using v12, on the create url function you can pass the locale as option.

`keyCloakClient.createLoginUrl({locale: 'it'});`

This adds an `&ui_locales=it` appendix to the url and loads the Keycloak app in the specific language.

See [KeycloakLoginOptions](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/17b374f53af275099f93a2d5c0bf13614cc11b8f/adapters/oidc/js/src/main/resources/keycloak.d.ts#L191).

Answer (score 0):

You should try something beforehand:
- dont set any default language in your kc-client-config nore in the user prefs
- change your browser language to french and try to login. Is the login page in french?
- change your brwoser language to english any try to login. Is the login page in english?

We have a multi-language app here (Angular/Spring) and found that the language is determined by browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

To indicate the preferred language for the UI you can set the `Accept-Language` header on the request and that's all.