# How to force Keycloak to use the browsers default language?

Tags: internationalization, keycloak, freemarker

I have setup a Keycloak Server with my own theme.
The Keycloak should support multiple languages but I do not want to display a selector.

Instead, the Keycloak should fall back to the default browser language.
In Keycloak 22 it doesn't look like this is an option that one simply configure in the admin console. There you can only enable multiple languages, which automatically displays that language selector.

What is the best way to make Keycloak fall back to the default browser language?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of programming I got this solution:

1. Delete the Selector in the template.ftl
2. create a js script with this code:

```js
// Function to get the value of a query parameter from a URL
function getQueryParamValue(url, paramName) {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(new URL(url).search);
  return params.get(paramName);
}

// Function to get the user's browser language
function getUserBrowserLanguage() {
  const userLanguage = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
  return userLanguage.split("-")[0]; // Extract language code (e.g., "en" from "en-US")
}

// Function to reload the page with the kc_locale query parameter added
function reloadWithLocaleQueryParam(locale) {
  const currentURL = window.location.href;
  const existingLocale = getQueryParamValue(currentURL, "ui_locales");

  // If kc_locale parameter doesn't exist or is empty, add it to the URL
  if (!existingLocale) {
    const delimiter = currentURL.includes("?") ? "&" : "?";
    const newURL = `${currentURL}${delimiter}ui_locales=${locale}`;
    window.location.href = newURL;
  }
}

// Get user's browser language and reload with kc_locale parameter if needed
const userLanguage = getUserBrowserLanguage();
reloadWithLocaleQueryParam(userLanguage);
```

3. add the script to the template.ftl:

```html
<head>
....
   <script src="${url.resourcesPath}/js/languageManager.js"></script>
</head>
```

Note that this solution is based on this:
[How to pass keycloak login page language with URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58682967/how-to-pass-keycloak-login-page-language-with-url)

Specifically the solution relies on the query parameter "ui_locales" which works for keycloak 13.0.0+ according to @Míra
For keycloak >7.0.0 & <13.0.0 use kc_locale.